# Assigning Labels to Cluster Id's with ML.Net

Tags: c#, cluster-analysis, ml.net

I'm new to ML.Net and AI in general. I have a dataset with sale counts. Over a rolling 12 month period, sales generally have 3 phases - low, medium, and high (spikes). The idea is I will train a KMeans clustering model on previous years data, then use that model to identify what phase of the year we are currently in.

I have the model successfully identifying 3 different clusters, however the cluster id's never seem to be the same. For example, one time the model may say the high phase is a 1, then the next time it'll say it's a 3. Shouldn't I be able to use this model to know that a cluster id 1 is the "low" phase, 2 is the "medium" phase, etc.?

```
string featuresColumnName = "Features";
var pipeline = context.Transforms
    .Concatenate(featuresColumnName, "SaleCount")
    .Append(context.Clustering.Trainers.KMeans(featuresColumnName, numberOfClusters: 3));

var model = pipeline.Fit(data);
var predictor = context.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<SaleModel, SalePrediction>(model);

var prediction = predictor.Predict(new SaleModel(1600));
```

I could totally be misunderstanding the algorithm and it's purpose. If that's the case, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post a snippet of your data? If you have labeled data, so have the target phase associated with every row, you should go for multiclass classification, not clustering. Clustering is for unlabeled data, trying to figure out whether there is grouping and what is the grouping.

Comment: That makes sense. So, essentially I should use clustering to manually comb through the groupings to find similarities, then use those datapoints to assign labels. Once I have the dataset with labels, use a multiclass classification model?

Comment: if you don't have labels on the data, you can use clustering and see if your data is really clustered on the three low, medium, high you mention, than you can assign the respective cluster centers to them, and go for multiclass. 

But if you have typical timeseries data, and peaks, you might want to look at TimeSeries analysis. 

See:https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/tree/master/samples/csharp/end-to-end-apps/Regression-SalesForecast

and:
https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/tree/master/docs/samples/Microsoft.ML.Samples/Dynamic/Transforms/TimeSeries

Comment: I'd give automl a try too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/concept-automated-ml